# Current User nil after kill app on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios7.1

I am coding an iOS app with parse SDK. I check user logged in by

```
[PFUser currentUser] != nil
```

This is my case (on iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1):

> 1. Open app.
> 2. Login by account on parse database.
> 3. Logged in success, with `currentUser != nil`
> 4. On main screen (after login) I press iPhone's home button (2 times).
> 5. I kill the app
> 6. I open the app. And it not logged.

I debug and see `PFUser currentUser` is `nil` when open app second time.

I check it when the app is killed by user, and open again. It works fine on iOS 8, but when I check on iOS 7.1, `currentUser` is `nil`. It looks like it logged out automatic or `currentUser` did not save.

I am using parse SDK 1.7.5. A new version is 1.8.0, maybe I should update it?

### Fixed.

This is my mistake, in `AppDelegate` I set `rootViewController` before `Setup Parse` and check `currentUser` in `viewWillAppear`. I make this issue, maybe in iOS > 8.0 the `viewWillAppear` will be called slower on iOS 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Every simulator you can use with XCode is its own "sand box" per se. This means that if I'm logged in as a user in Parse with the iPhone 6+ simulator using iOS 8.4, and then I shut down the simulator and run my app on the iPhone 6+ simulator using iOS 8.3 then the app shows that I'm no longer logged in. Try it for yourself. This is normal behavior. If this is not what you are experiencing, then please elaborate your issue and explain in detail what actions you have taken in order to resolve this issue. Your issue could very well be caused by something entirely different that what I think it may be.